# Google pixel android10 not supporting configChange from manifest

Tags: android

As my application supports only portrait mode for mobile devices.
As I select device Auto-rotate on.
But when I install this application on Google Pixel Android 10. It rotates in landscape mode.
As I mentioned in the manifest  `android:configChanges="screenLayout|keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation".`But still the WebView rotates in landscape mode.
How to handle this scenario.
Also when the device will rotate in landscape mode in `onConfigurationChanged()` method will return from the function.
Still, it rotates in landscape mode.

Please suggest to me.

Thanks

```
android:configChanges="screenLayout|keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"

fun onConfigurationChanged(){
if(Mobile){
return
}
```

Expected is The view should not rotate in landscape mode as it is supported for portrait mode only for the mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest.xml file add following line to every activity declared: -

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

It will make sure that your application will be in portrait mode only.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:configChanges="screenLayout|keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
```

> Above line will not prevent it to go to landscap mode. It will prevent view to regenerate and this how there is no need to save the states of the views.

**To restrict app in portrait mode you should add below line in your activity tag.**

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Also the method **onConfigurationChanged** is called when configuration has been changed. Means after changing orientation it is being called so you can not write something inside of it to prevent activity to go into landscap mode.

> Or you can try this

```
if(CommonUtils.dpFromPx(this, resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat())>=600){
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR
        }
        else{
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR
        }
```

> and the mothod dpFromPx is:

```
 public static float dpFromPx(final Context context, final float px) {
        return px / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I want to do at runtime then how will I handle this as for mobile device it should be in portrait mode and for tablet the screen should support both in landscape and portrait mode. Can you please suggest me the solution. This auto rotate was happened only on android 10.

Comment: Okay then you can try `requestedOrientation`.

Comment: First of all you have to check display is it more them 600dp then its a tablet or big display not a phone. If its phone you can set ORIENTATION SENSOR OFF and if its tablet then turn ON SENSOR